# Store for loop iteration variable into a new incremented variable

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I would like to store variable value for each for iteration into a new variable with new name. I need the final result to be variable not array.

**FOR LOOP:**

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($_FILES['file']['name']);$i++) {
$file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
$new_file_name = strtolower($file);
$final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);     
}
```

Than inside this loop I need something like that:

```
$data1 = $final_file;
```

Where $data1 should increment the name each time the loop goes.

at the end it should generate something like this:

```
$data1 = $final_file; - final_file have value of the first loop iteration
$data2 = $final_file; - final_file have value of the second loop iteration
$data3 = $final_file; - ....
$data4 = $final_file;
$data5 = $final_file;
```

Comment: Seems pretty similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31786328/3933332

Comment: I made a few changes, the other question was deleted.

Comment: Why do you not use an array? Fill the array in the for loop with `$data[$i] = $final_filename;` and later use it: `$data[1], $data[2], $data[3], ...`

Comment: Hi Mario, that made it work. Thanks ! if you wish you can post it as answer.

Comment: Of course i can do ;-) Please edit my answer if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @JohnSiniger And that isn't just what I wrote as comment 2 hours ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786328/how-to-store-variable-into-array-and-than-bind-the-array-value#comment51501457_31786328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$data should be an array. Fill the array in the for loop with `$data[$i] = $final_filename;`

Later you can access the file names like this: `$data[1], $data[2], $data[3], ...`

Answer (score 1):

Setting a variable dynamically can be done using an extra `$`:

```
$i = 1;
$variable_name = 'data' . $i;
$$variable_name = 'my value';
```

After that code `$data1` will be set to "my value".

However, I would encourage you to use an array with the values instead.